# Redirect non-local connections to HTTPS in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I'm trying to force HTTPS on remote connections and forward all traffic that is not from the `192.168.0` net to https://$host$request_uri but allow access on local connections.

In apache2 I had

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from 192.168.0
Allow from 127
Deny from all
```

in the HTTP hosts' config and had to manually change to HTTPS after getting a 403.

Ideally I'd like to add some code to the HTTP section instead of into every server since I setup a lot of subdomains.

I already read the answers from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom) and know I can add

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

But then all traffic is forwarded. I only want to forward REMOTE connections. Mainly to reduce overhead on local connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the [HttpGeoModule](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html).

By adding ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/380843/156536))

```
geo $remote {
    default http;
    192.168.0.0/24 0;
    127.0.0.0/8 0;
}
```

to my http section and adding

```
if ($remote = $scheme) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

to my default-snippet I achieved what I wanted.