# nginx different root based on host ip

Tags: nginx

Does anyone know of a method to use a different server root based on the remote host's IP? This fails with a "root not allowed here" message:

```
if ($remote_addr = myip) {
    root /some/other/root
}
```

The goal: serve files from a test directory to my static IP for development.

Unfortunately, I'm migrating a site to wordpress, so it needs to be set up with the correct port/hostname or else I'd simple set up a location /mytestdir {} block or separate server block with a port for testing. Wordpress is annoying in that if you set it up at mydomain.com:1234, it 's a lot of trouble to fix when you move it to mydomain.com (without a port).

I can set up a dev server as mydomain.com on my local network, but I would love to know how to do this in nginx on the same server.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: I'm well aware of that process, though I'd still like to know about the nginx config. I'm generally use apache or lighttpd. Perhaps the process is greatly improved, but it used to be a royal pain migrating wp directories. I wish they'd just use things like src="/path/file" without the protocol/host.

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered elsewhere. There seem to be 2 strategies:

1. Using the nginx geo module.
   [Nginx - How to redirect users with certain IP to special page](https://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page)
2. Using a variable for the root dir.
   [Nginx document root based on client ip?](https://serverfault.com/questions/738420/nginx-document-root-based-on-client-ip)