# Nginx document root based on client ip?

Tags: nginx

Can I serve a different document root on nginx based on client ips? Basically I would like the same url to serve a different branch of my code for my client ip.

For example, this is what I would expect the config to be:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name some.server.name;

  client_max_body_size 10M;

  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/json;

  root {{ deploy_directory }};

  location /robots.txt {}

  if ($remote_addr ~ "^(<ip>|<ip>|<ip>)$") {
    root <some other root>
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    log_not_found off;
    gzip_static on;
    expires     max;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
    add_header  Last-Modified "";
    add_header  ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

But that doesnt load

Comment: Yes, you certainly can.

Comment: @AlexeyTen How? It wont let me - ip based if blocks are only allowed inside the location blocks

Comment: _ip based if blocks are only allowed inside the location blocks_ — not true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
root /$root;

set $root default/path;
if ($remote_addr ~ "^(127\.0\.0\.1|10\.20\.30\.40|111\.222\.33\.44)$") {
    set $root another/path;
}
```

**Do not** forget to escape dots in regexp for IPs.

Answer (score 2):

You can also combine Alexey Ten's answer with the geo module as mentioned in [Nginx - How to redirect users with certain IP to special page](https://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page)
This makes it easier to match multiple IP addresses due to CIDR notation and ranges support.

E.g.

```
geo $geo_host {
    default       0;
    127.0.0.1/16  1;
    1.2.3.4       1;
}

server {
    ... # Skipping details unrelated to this example.
    root /$root;

    set $root default/path;
    if ($geo_host = 1) {
        set $root other/path;
    }
}
```

This can also be combined with proxies, e.g. Varnish.
This example has only the `server {}` contents, see the `geo` block in the above example.

```
server {
    ... # Skipping details unrelated to this example.

    set $proxy_host maintenance.example.org;
    location / {
        if ($geo_host = 1) {
            set $proxy_host $host;
        }

        proxy_pass http://varnish;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        ... # Your other proxy config.
    }
}
```

This example redirects everyone not on the `geo` whitelist to see a maintenance page (which is served by whatever http server is after the Varnish cache). Varnish gets passed the real host for those on the whitelist and the maintenance host for those not on the whitelist.