# NGINX TCP Load Balancing "if" directive is NOT allowed here in "stream" context

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am hoping someone can help me with the following. I am trying to setup a reverse proxy for load balancing using `nginx` over tcp/udp.

I want to be able to redirect some traffic based the client ip address that is connecting up to the proxy server. For this I am using the built-in nginx variable `$remote_addr`.

The version of nginx I am using is: `nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`.

The error message I am getting is: `nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here`

This is my config file looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx/pid

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

stream {
    upstream prod_backend {
        server 192.168.137.129:23;
    }
    upstream test_backend {
        server 192.168.137.131:23;
    }

    server {
        listen 23;

        if ( $remote_addr = 192.168.137.132 ) {
            proxy_pass test_backend;
        }

        proxy_pass prod_backend;
    }
}

http {
}
```

After seeing this answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page), I have tried using the Geo module but get the same problem.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx/pid

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

stream {
    upstream prod_backend {
        server 192.168.137.129:23;
    }
    upstream test_backend {
        server 192.168.137.131:23;
    }

    geo $test_site {
        default 0;
        192.168.137.132 1;
    }

    server {
        listen 23;

        if ( $test_site ) {
            proxy_pass test_backend;
        }

        proxy_pass prod_backend;
    }
}

http {
}
```

when I run the above version I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "geo" directive is not allowed here
```

I am obviously doing something wrong but don't know what!

Comment: Because you can use "if" only within server and location context. And your stream section use main context. The same thing with geo.

Comment: But if you look at my 1st example, the "if" statement is within the server context. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: It's because your server section inside stream which in main context, imho

Comment: But you cant put the server section outside the stream.

Comment: What do you mean? It's because server block can be placed only in http context - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server

Comment: Hmm. That's not correct as per the documentation I have been following here.  see here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/.

Comment: This config is not for http traffic. Are you saying I can use the http context and this will still work? I can try that.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html because "if" it's a directive of http_rewrite module, you can't use it inside stream module. You can use it only within ```http{ server { ... } }```

Comment: I see. Thanks ALex_hha. So I need to look for an alternative method of filtering ip traffic with: stream { server { ... } }

Comment: found the alternative method by using the map function which is supported in the stream context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user @Alex_hha pointed out, the "if" directive can only be used within the `http` directive.

After some research around this area I have now found a solution to the problem.

If you are using the `stream` directive for generic `TCP/UDP` traffic an alternative to the `if` statement is to use the [map function](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.html).

Using this method my config file now looks like this:

```
stream {
   upstream prod_backend {
      server 192.168.137.129:23;
   }

   upstream test_backend {
      server 192.168.137.131:23;
   }

   map $remote_addr $backend_svr {
      192.168.137.140:23 "test_backend";
      default "prod_backend";
   }

   server {
      listen 23;
      proxy pass $backend_svr;
   }
}
```

In this example, if a client connects with the `IP` address of `192.168.137.140` it will get sent to the `test_backend` upstream block.

The version of nginx I am using is: `nginx/1.12.1 (Ubuntu)`.