# nginx TCP forwarding with GeoIP

Tags: nginx, tcp, geoip

CentOS 7.8

nginx version: `nginx/1.18.0`

`yum install nginx-module-geoip`

`yum install GeoIP GeoIP-data`

Then, GeoIO runs well with HTTP(S).

I need nginx to forward a TCP port, which is only open to CN
add to nginx.conf

```
stream {
    geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
    log_format proxy '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                 '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                 '$session_time "$upstream_addr" '
                 '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/tcp-access.log proxy ;
    open_log_file_cache off;
    include tcpconf.d/*.conf;
}
```

xxxx.com.conf

```
server {
    listen   11111;
 
    proxy_pass  127.0.0.1:31688;
}
```

Forwarding 11111 to 31688 works OK.

add to server{

restart error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with "if", which you should avoid as much as possible.  Have a look at eg. [nginx config example](https://gist.github.com/kmjones1979/fcabb4731bbf85b9c50189e90d76b1c1)  for another way.

There, a map is used to test the country code. A very simple version would be:

```
map $geoip_country_code $allow_visit {
    default no;
    CN yes;
    BE yes;
}
 
server{
  if ($allow_visit = no) {
    return 403;
  }
}
```

But this can't be used by stream, since "if" is part of the http_rewrite module.  See eg. [if in stream](https://serverfault.com/questions/886997/nginx-tcp-load-balancing-if-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-stream-context).  I tried the following construct with success:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 9998;
    return 403;
  }
}

stream {
  geoip_country         /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
  map $geoip_country_code $be_server {
    BE   127.0.0.1:9997;
    default 127.0.0.1:9998;

  }
  server {
    listen 9999;
    proxy_pass  $be_server;
  }
  server {
    listen 9997;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8889;
  }
}
```

Only requests from Belgium are allowed.

Comment: I edit the question，please see it

Comment: I think I found a way out.

Comment: real situation 9998 is tcp port ,no http .I create a 9998.conf listen 9998 and 8889,copy stream{} to nginx.conf.no change BE,restart nginx.can access from CN and JP

Comment: I don't understand.  Please add your current configuration in a readable way to your question.

Comment: Like SSH, how to allow only CN connections. I thought of using nginx for forwarding

Comment: Please add your current configuration in a readable way to your question.