# Nginx - If IP then proxy_pass else return 403

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ip-address

I am trying to proxy_pass users with certain IPs to `http://server1` and certain other users to `http://server2`. I'd like to return 403 if the user doesn't match any IP.
Here's what I have:

```
geo $userGroup1 {
        default 0;
        192.168.178.2 1;
}
geo $userGroup2 {
        default 0;
        192.168.178.3 1;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
         
        server_tokens off;
        server_name _;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        
        server_name _;

        location / {
            if ($userGroup1) {
                    proxy_pass http://server1 
            }
            if ($userGroup2) {
                    proxy_pass http://server2
            }
            
            # return 403 <-- returns 403 for all users
            
        }
}
```

How would my config need to be changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx - How to redirect users with certain IP to special page](https://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page)

Answer (score 2):

Have finally gotten around testing this, do keep in mind that "proxy_pass" cannot contain a URI in example below, use an IP address.

If you want to forwad to another server by URI, you could maybe use "return" or "rewrite" instead of "proxy_pass";
For more information click [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

```
geo $remote_addr $userGroup {
        default             0;
        192.168.178.2       1;
        192.168.178.3       2;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    location / {
            if ($userGroup = 1) {
                    proxy_pass https://192.168.178.201;
            }
            if ($userGroup = 2) {
                    proxy_pass https://192.168.178.202;
            }
            
            return 403; # Anyone else would get a 403
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the directive '**break**' inside the 'if' statement, like this:

```
geo $userGroup1 {
       default 0;
       192.168.178.2 1;
}

geo $userGroup2 {
        default 0;
        192.168.178.3 1;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
         
        server_tokens off;
        server_name _;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        
        server_name _;

        location / {
            if ($userGroup1) {
                    proxy_pass http://server1;
                    break; # <-------- HERE
            }
            if ($userGroup2) {
                    proxy_pass http://server2;
                    break; # <-------- HERE
            }
            
            return 403; # <-- returns 403 for all users
            
        }
}
```